# How to make btnListShuffleRepeat work on android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a button to switch between test upon clicking it but every time i click the button the app crashes. Also please make the code and explanation as simple as possible as i am very new to Java coding. Thank you

I have tried changing the multiple method of .getText() that i can find on the internet but it doesn't work and i try assigning my button to a string and try the code and it still does not work

```
public void playListShuffleRepeat(View btnView){
    if (btnListShuffleRepeat.getText().toString().equals("LIST")){
        btnListShuffleRepeat.setText("LOOP");
        //Loop function
    }
    if(btnListShuffleRepeat.getText().equals("LOOP")){
        btnListShuffleRepeat.setText("SHUFFLE");
        //Shuffle function
    }
    if(btnListShuffleRepeat.getText().equals("SHUFFLE")){
        btnListShuffleRepeat.setText("LIST");
        //List function
    }
}
```

I expect the end result to be my button working and being possible to switch its text

Comment: Ignore the functions i intend to add them after my button works

Comment: Now i have added additional lines of code so the gettext function word but the settext function does not. anyone has any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `btnListShuffleRepeat` to `btnView`.

```
public void playListShuffleRepeat(View btnView){
    if (btnView.getText().toString().equals("LIST")){
        btnView.setText("LOOP");
        //Loop function
    }
    else if(btnView.getText().equals("LOOP")){
        btnView.setText("SHUFFLE");
        //Shuffle function
    }
    else if(btnView.getText().equals("SHUFFLE")){
        btnView.setText("LIST");
        //List function
    }
}
```

First you have to get the reference of the button view.
If you create a button variable like

```
Button btn;
```

Then you have to either alloc a memory for it (`btn = new Button(Context)`) or you have to get the reference from the xml (`btn = findViewById(R.id.yor_btn_id)`). Otherwise it will through you an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help but my teacher was able to help me apparently I had to change if() to else if()

Comment: However i have another problem that i encounter that is when i press the button to change text, the respective code that is suppose to activate doesn't work. Like when i am playing the music half way through and click the button to change it function like from list function to loop function, the loop would not execute

Comment: edited the answer as your teacher suggested, so that it helps others